# Was "The Death of Grass" originally named "No Blade of Grass" or vice versa?

Tags: story-identification

I have a strong memory of a SF story entitled "No Blade of Grass" that appeared decades ago in one of the major SF magazines of the time, probably *Analog*.  It now appears, from Googling, that the story was entitled "*The Death of Grass*", and was a book.

When I plug "No Blade of Grass" into Google, I get [this](https://diaboliquemagazine.com/unrelenting-bleakness-no-blade-of-grass-fifty-years-later/), which is a review of a movie. The summary of the movie is very similar to what I remember of the story. However, I am 100% certain that I am not remembering a movie or a movie review.  I am remembering printed matter.

**Question:**  Was the original version of *The Death of Grass* reprinted as *No Blade of Grass.*  Or vice versa?

Comment: I don't know why this keeps making me think of the novel-within-a-novel _[The Grasshopper Lies Heavy](https://the-man-in-the-high-castle.fandom.com/wiki/The_Grasshopper_lies_Heavy_(Novel))_ from _The Man in the High Castle_.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, *The Death of Grass* (by John Christopher) was printed with the US variant title *[No Blade of Grass](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?517001)*, after the publisher complained that the original title sounded like "*[something out of a gardening catalogue](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Death_of_Grass)"*

It wasn't printed as a short story, but it was [serialised](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1987834).

Comment: LOL cool anecdote btw!

Comment: I actually have a copy of this with the title *No Blade of Grass* -- never knew it had another title!